# Let V be the set of all polynomials over $ \mathbb{Q}$ of degree 2 together with the zero polynomial. Is V a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think the answer is no but don't know how to prove it!

Comment: Can you subtract you degree 2 polynomials to give something that is not strictly degree 2 and not zero?

Comment: Show the sum of two quadratic polynomials is not necessarily quadratic with a counter-example.

Comment: Oh I see, this is too trivial.. for any quadratic polynomial f(x), -f(x) will do the job...@Bernard  sorry for posting such a trivial question

Comment: @Infinity: you can not simply take $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ since the zero polynomial is in $V$, but you could consider $f(x)$ and $-f(x) + c$, where $c$ is some non-zero integer for example.